# How do I only bring in rows that have changed since last ssis run

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a ssis package that runs every hour to bring in sales. currently I am bringing in all rows from the beginning of the business, but would like to only bring in rows that are new and those that have been changed since last run. what I need to do is somehow get ssis to create a last run column and then be able to use that time to filter all incoming rows that are either new or have been changed. not sure how go about doing this, any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Please demonstrate what you have tried so far, which articles you have reviewed that almost worked but didn't etc. May be a good idea to read https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask so we have a well formulated question to answer with all the information required.  Thanks.

Comment: @GandRalph that's a very clear question for everyone who's used SSIS or worked with ETL in general.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I work with SSIS on a daily basis and understand the question perfectly.  I am trying to get the person asking to put in a little effort and demonstrate what they have tried so far.  We are not here to simply tell people how to do things, we are here to help them help themselves.

Comment: @GandRalph I have tried using a OLE DB command column that insert system date into a new column every time the project runs. I just haven't been able to find a good way of pulling this date into the package to filter the incoming rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) to retrieve changes made to a table since a specific version number. This can catch deletions which you can't handle with auditing columns.

Change Tracking is available in all SQL Server editions (ie even Express) so you don't have to worry about licensing.

Copying from the docs, you can load all changes since a specific version with :

```
SELECT  
    CT.ProductID, P.Name, P.ListPrice,  
    CT.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION, CT.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS,  
    CT.SYS_CHANGE_CONTEXT  
FROM  
    SalesLT.Product AS P  
RIGHT OUTER JOIN  
    CHANGETABLE(CHANGES SalesLT.Product, @last_synchronization_version) AS CT  
ON  
    P.ProductID = CT.ProductID
```

`@last_synchronization_version` is the database version used the last time the ETL job run.

There are various ways to get the last version.

One way would be to store the current version number with [CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/change-tracking-current-version-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) when the ETL job starts into a table and use it as the `@last_synchronization_version` for the next run. The first time `@last_synchronization_version` would be `0`.

You could use an OLEDB Command to load the last stored version from eg a JobHistory table and the current version at the same time :

```
select max(NextVersion) as VersionSince, CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION() as NextVersion
from JobHistory;
```

And store the next version with at the end of the package :

```
insert into JobHistory (...,NextVersion)
valures (...,@NextVersion)
```

This way you can easily retrieve all changes made since the last run.

Another option is to include each row's version number in the results by adding the  `SYS_CHANGE_VERSION` column to the query

```
SELECT  
    CT.ProductID, P.Name, P.ListPrice,  
    CT.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION, CT.SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS,  
    CT.SYS_CHANGE_CONTEXT  ,
    CT.SYS_CHANGE_VERSION as TrackingVersion
FROM  
    SalesLT.Product AS P  
RIGHT OUTER JOIN  
    CHANGETABLE(CHANGES SalesLT.Product, @last_synchronization_version) AS CT  
ON  
    P.ProductID = CT.ProductID
```

On each run you can retrieve the maximum version from the target table and use it to load changes from the source.

```
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(TrackingVersion),0) as LastVersion
From TargetTable
```

Another option would be to store the overall database version per row, instead of each row's version.

Answer (score 2):

You look at the columns `createdAt` and `updatedAt`, which you meticulously maintain for all the rows in your table, probably using triggers (although you might do this through application logic as well).

Let me assume that `updatedAt` is set when a row is created.  Then you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.updatedAt >= @LastReadDate;
```

Comment: This might sound very stupid, but how would I be able to set @LastReadDate so that is changes every time the package runs? currently I would have to manually set the date, at least that what it looks like to me, I could very well be missing something.

Comment: @Cade . . . You need to remember it each time to read from the table.  That would be part of the application code.